# QgsPalLayerSettings error

Tags: qgis

I'm trying to label vector feature:

```
#############################
palyr = QgsPalLayerSettings()
layer = iface.activeLayer()
palyr.enabled = True
palyr.fieldName = 'Txt'
palyr.writeToLayer(layer)
layer.triggerRepaint()
############################
```

With this code I get an error:

```
'QgsPalLayerSettings' object has no attribute 'writeToLayer'
```

I'm working in Qgis 3.2.

Can someone help me with this.

Answer (score 2):

The API for labeling has changed significantly in QGIS 3.x, and the old "writeToLayer" methods are no longer supported.

Take a look at QgsVectorLayer.labeling(), and the class QgsVectorLayerSimpleLabeling. An adaption of your code would be something like:

```
label_settings = QgsPalLayerSettings()
label_settings.drawLabels = True
label_settings.fieldName = 'Txt'

layer = iface.activeLayer()
layer.setLabeling(QgsVectorLayerSimpleLabeling(label_settings))
layer.triggerRepaint()
```

Comment: Nice, it works perfectly. I just added this line before triggerRepaint: layer.setLabelsEnabled(True)
Thnx.