# Getting labeling field in variable and changing labeling field with PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, labeling, fields-attributes, pyqgis-3

I working with QGIS 3.20. I want to write a PyQGIS script to automate switching the field used for labeling in numerous layers. Currently the layers are labeled from values of a field that is different for each layer.

I thought I will follow this procedure:

1. Get the field name that is currently used for labeling (say field `"X"`) in a variable
2. Add a new field `"Label"` and populate its values according to the values in field `"X"`
3. Set the labeling field to the `"Label"` field

I know how to do number 2 and I am looking for a way to do number 1 and 3.
So my questions are: how do I get the labeling field name (to store in a variable)? How do I change the labeling field?

In the UI this is the labeling field I want to access and change (however its name is different for each layer):

[image: Labeling field]

What would be the way to go?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My answer is based on two answers :

[Getting label feature with PyQGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/325009/getting-label-feature-with-pyqgis) from Leo Cardona for step 1

[QgsPalLayerSettings error](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/292136/qgspallayersettings-error) from ndawson for step 3

This is the code used for step 1 and step 3 :

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()    
# STEP 1
labeling = layer.labeling()
palyr = labeling.settings()
currently_used_field_name = palyr.fieldName
print (currently_used_field_name)
# this will print : X

#STEP 3
new_label_field = "Label"
label_settings = QgsPalLayerSettings()
label_settings.drawLabels = True
label_settings.fieldName = new_label_field
layer.setLabeling(QgsVectorLayerSimpleLabeling(label_settings))
layer.triggerRepaint()
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That was exactly what I needed! Could you also tell me how to distinguish if a layer has single labelling (based on the values of a field) or rule based labeling?

Comment: @mikmar you can use `palyr.getLabelExpression().isField()` wich is going to return a boolean, `TRUE` if your label is based only on a field and `FALSE` if your label is based on an expression. See the doc of QgsExpression.

https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/core/QgsExpression.html#qgis.core.QgsExpression.isField